# ¿Cómo envio una imagen desde android studio a mysql?

Tags: mysql, android, phpmyadmin, imagen, android-volley

Tengo este codigo y al cargar la imagen en la carpeta de xampp, me carga un archivo de 0 bytes, al mandarla a mysql, da error, no entiendo donde esta el error. No se si esta mal la consulta, en el codigo de java o en el php. al comentar las lineas de la consulta en php, la aplicacion funciona, pero carga una imagen de 0 bytes.

El codigo de php:

```
<?php
$hostname="localhost";
$database = "despensa";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$conexion = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $database);
$nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
$descripcion = $_POST["descripcion"];
$imagen = $_POST["imagen"];

$path = "imagenes/$nombre.jpg";
$url = "http://$hostname/$path";

file_put_contents($path, base64_decode($imagen));
$bytesArchivo = file_get_contents($path);

$sql = "INSERT INTO recetas VALUES (?,?,?)";
$stm = $conexion->prepare($sql);
&stm->bind_param('sss', $nombre, $descripcion, $bytesArchivo);

if($stm->execute()){
    echo "registra";
}else{
    echo "noRegistra";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
           protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {

                String nombre = et_nombre.getText().toString();
                String descripcion = et_descripcion.getText().toString();
                String imagen = convertirImgString(imgBitmap);

                Map<String, String> parametros = new HashMap<>();
                parametros.put("nombre", nombre);
                parametros.put("descripcion", descripcion);
                parametros.put("imagen", imagen);
                return parametros;

            }
        };
 private String convertirImgString(Bitmap imgBitmap) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream array = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      //  imgBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, array);
        byte[] imagenByte = array.toByteArray();
        String imagenString = Base64.encodeToString(imagenByte, Base64.DEFAULT);
        return "";
    }
    private File crearImagen() throws IOException{

        String nombreImagen = "foto_";
        File directorio = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File imagen = File.createTempFile(nombreImagen, ".jpg", directorio);
        rutaimagen = imagen.getAbsolutePath();
        return imagen;

    }
```

Comment: GRacias por tu contribuciòn, te sugerimos revisar [answer] y edita tu pregunta, agregando informaciòn de como resuelve el problema que expone el OP en su pregunta, saludos.